# how to get data into different tabs using parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json

i have made webservice and am fetching data from that using webmethod.i have made two functions is it possible to call a single websrvice in a single function using two parseJSON function?

it is randomly showing me data i want the data to be displayed in two different tabs. some times it is displaying only in single tab and some times it is displaying in wrong tab.

here below is the piece of code

```
function contacts(){
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: webMethod,
            processData: true,
            data: { 'country': 'india' },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'parseJSON',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                $detail = $("div.presenter-tabs");


                $("div#india", $detail).html($('#contactUsTemplate').render(data));
            },
            error: function (response, status, data) {
                var c = status; //For testing purpose
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: webMethod,
            processData: true,
            data: { 'country': 'out of india' },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'parseJSON',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                $detail1 = $("div.presenter-tabs");

                $("div#outofindia",  $detail1).html($('#contactUsTemplate').render(data));
            },
            error: function (response, status, data) {
                var c = status; //For testing purpose
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks fishy to me:

```
$detail1 = $("div.presenter-tabs");

$("div#outofindia",  $detail1).html($('#contactUsTemplate').render(data));
```

Try changing that to:

```
$("div#outofindia").html($('#contactUsTemplate').render(data));
```

And likewise in the "India" callback:

```
$("div#india").html($('#contactUsTemplate').render(data));
```